# Determening correlation between $X$ and $Y$ knowing $\hat{\beta}=0.23$ and $\text{SE}(\hat{\beta})=0.08$

Tags: regression, linear

**In a linear regression with about 100 observations we have the following estimate for $\beta$: $\hat{\beta}=0.23$ with $\text{SE}(\hat{\beta})=0.08$. 
Does data suggest a correlation between these two variables?**

I think there is a positive correlation because $\hat{\beta} > 0$. But I do not know how to show that $\hat{\beta}$ is significantly different from 0.

Answer (score 0):

It does show you a positive correlation, since  $\hat{\beta} = cov(y,x) / var(x)$ and var(x) can never be negative. (Replace x with a partialled out x in case you have a multivariate linear regression.)

I heavily advise to review the basics of linear regression.

Comment: This textbook question is looking for a *statistical test* of the null hypothesis $\beta=0$ against the alternative hypothesis $\beta\ne 0.$

Comment: But the funny thing is  hypothesis testing not curriculum. So that is why I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Please have a look a some basic statistcs book. The test statistic is super easy: t = (beta - 0) / se

Comment: If hypothesis testing is not in the curriculum, then some equivalent form of statistical reasoning must be on it, for otherwise this would be a useless (and frustrating) question.  We are able to answer questions but--unless you tell us explicitly--we are unable to guess what is in your curriculum.